# Dictionary in Java hashtables

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

I have a trouble with my program. I should to create a program like a dictionary. So I probably did it but it does not work. I have a menu so it should add/edit/delete word in file. please can you help me with my program, i think there are all understandable in my code. the problem is it can not find words in file in function

`editWord, deleteWord. and serachTranslation`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Dictionary{

   public static Hashtable<String, String> dictionary = new Hashtable<String, String>();

   public static void main(String []args)throws InputMismatchException, IOException{

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("dict.in")));
      String line = null;
         while((line = br.readLine())!= null ){
            String [] words = line.split("\\s+");
            String kaz = words[0];
            String eng = words[1];
            Dictionary.dictionary.put(kaz,eng);
         }
      menu();
   }

   public static void menu(){

      //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");

      System.out.println("1 - Add/Edit/Delete word");
      System.out.println("2 - Search translation");
      //System.out.println("3 - Switch language");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
      int choose  = sc.nextInt();
      switch(choose){
         case 1: secondMenu();
         break;
         case 2: searchTranslation();
         break;
         //case 3: System.out.print("It works 3 case");
         //break;
         default: menu();
         break;
      }
   }

   public static void secondMenu() throws InputMismatchException{
      System.out.println("1 - Add");
      System.out.println("2 - Edit");
      System.out.println("3 - Delete");
      System.out.println("4 - Back");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
      int choose  = sc.nextInt();
      switch(choose){
         case 1: addWord();
         break;
         case 2: editWord();
         break;
         case 3: deleteWord();
         break;
         case 4: menu();
         break;
         default: secondMenu();
         break;
      }  
   }
   public static void addWord(){
      Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter word in Kazakh language: ");
      String kaz  = w.next();
      System.out.println("Enter word in English language: ");
      String eng = w.next();
      Dictionary.dictionary.put(kaz,eng);
      System.out.println("Sucsess");
      menu();
   }

   public static void editWord(){
      Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter word which you want to change: ");
      String word = w.next();

      Iterator s = Dictionary.dictionary.keySet().iterator();

      while (s.hasNext()) {
      String key = (String) s.next();
      Object value = Dictionary.dictionary.get(key);

         if(word==key){
            System.out.println("Enter new meaning of this word: ");
            String newWord = w.next();
            Dictionary.dictionary.remove(key);
            Dictionary.dictionary.put(word,newWord);
            menu();
         }
         if(word==value){
            System.out.println("Enter new meaning of this word: ");
            String newWord = w.next();
            Dictionary.dictionary.remove(value);
            Dictionary.dictionary.put(newWord,word);
            menu();
         }
      }

   }
   public static void deleteWord(){
      Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter word which you want to delete: ");
      String word = w.next();
      Iterator s = Dictionary.dictionary.keySet().iterator();

      while (s.hasNext()) {
      String key = (String) s.next();
      Object value = Dictionary.dictionary.get(key);

         if(word==key){
            Dictionary.dictionary.remove(key);
            menu();
         }
         if(word==value){
            Dictionary.dictionary.remove(value);
            menu();
         }
      }

   }

   public static void searchTranslation(){
      Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter word which you want to translate: ");
      String word = w.next();
      Iterator s = Dictionary.dictionary.keySet().iterator();
      while (s.hasNext()) {
      String key = (String) s.next();
      Object value = Dictionary.dictionary.get(key);

         if(word==key){
            System.out.println(word+" : "+Dictionary.dictionary.get(value));
            menu();
         }
         if(word==value){
            System.out.println(word+" : "+Dictionary.dictionary.get(key));
            menu();
         }
      }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a Hashtable (you should use HashMap, by the way), is to be able to find a value by key without iterating. Use its `get()` method to find the meaning of a word, `put()` to insert/update a meaning of a word, and `delete()` to delete a word with its meaning.

The problem is that you're using `==` to compare Strings, instead of `equals()`, but you shouldn't even have to compare anything if you used to map as it should be used, since the map would do the comparisons for you.

Comment: please can you correct my mistakes, because I really do not understand what is the my mistake?